# UITableView edit cell without changing underlying core data

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I have a tableview of dates that are calculated based on stored week periods from core data.  The tableview shows the results for each calculation:

Example:  Today's date - 80 weeks (the 80 comes from core data)

So tableview would show date for 80 weeks prior to today.

There are about a dozen of these dates listed in the tableview, different depending on the core data value.

If I want to allow the user to "override" the date that is presented, how can I do that?

So if they tapped the result in the tableview, I could take them to a view controller with a date picker, but how do I return that back into the tableview with the other items?  I'm assuming I'd have to make sure the tableview didn't reload on viewWillAppear as well..

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the extraneous date to the object that you are representing in the table view. Give it a new property `overrideDate` and check that first when configuring your cell.

Alternatively, if this is what you want, change the Core Data number based on the chosen date and save it. Depending on your setup (e.g. Fetched Results Controller with delegate enabled and implemented, like in the standard Xcode template), the table view should update correctly.